# Why two for statements will not run together in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to run a Python program to calculate the total and average charges that are contained within a CSV file.

I then want to calculate the total and average charge per invoice. The program calculates the total charges and average charges correctly, but the second for statement will not run. Both for statement run independently correctly.

```
import csv
f = open("transport.csv", "r")
reader = csv.DictReader(f)
charges_per_inv = dict()
inv_reader = csv.DictReader(f)
inv_dict = dict()

counter = 0
inv_counter = 1

for row in reader:
    batch_num = row['Batch#']
    if batch_num not in charges_per_inv:
        charges_per_inv [batch_num] = 0.0
    charges_per_inv [batch_num] += float(row['Amount'])
    counter = counter + 1                           
    #print charges_per_inv #Just a check

dvalue = [(v) for v in charges_per_inv.values()]     
#print dvalue
total = sum(dvalue)
average = float(total)/ counter
#print counter #Just a check
print "The total charges is, ", total
print "The average charge is, ", average

a = raw_input("Enter Invoice#: ")

for i in inv_reader:
    inv_num1 = i["Invoice#"]
    if inv_num1 == a:
        if inv_num1 not in inv_dict:
            inv_dict[inv_num1] = 0.0
        inv_dict[inv_num1] += float(i['Amount'])    
        inv_counter = inv_counter + 1
        print inv_dict #Just a check

inv_amount = [(v) for v in inv_dict.values()]
#print inv_amount
inv_total = sum(inv_amount)
inv_average = float(inv_total)/ inv_counter
#print inv_counter #Just a check
print "The total charges is, ", inv_total
print "The average charge is, ", inv_average
```

Here is the output for the program.

```
The total charges is,  9069.87
The average charge is,  72.55896
Enter Invoice#: 617537
The total charges is,  0
The average charge is,  0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Because the file's already been read by that point, so there's nothing for the second loop to do. You should close and reopen the file after the first loop, and move the instantiation of `inv_reader` to after that.

Better still, you should merge the loops into one - it'll be much more efficient.

Comment: Another solution would be to `f.seek(0)`after the first loop.

Comment: @Evpok: I think you'd need to `f.readline()` as well to skip the header line, or it would be treated as a record by the still-initialised `DictReader`.

Answer (score 2):

It's like you hand a glass full of water to the first loop and have it drink it, then hand the empty glass to the next loop.

Answer (score 1):

They both use the same underlying file-object (`f`). After the first loop, this has been exhausted. You could do this:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open("transport.csv"))
inv_reader = csv.DictReader(open("transport.csv"))
```

This way both readers have independent file-objects.

Answer (score 1):

Be also aware that, according to the documentation (http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.reader), the file should be open with the ‘b’ flag on platforms where that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You have created to csv readers (an iterable) using the same file object (also an iterable). When you consume the rows from the first csv reader (`reader`) you consume the lines of the file (`f`). When you come to iterate the second csv reader (`inv_reader`), the lines of the file object (`f`) have been consumed; there is nothing left to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

Here, for reference, is how I would neaten your code considerably. This is without alterations to its actual functionality. Note that if you have lots and lots of entries in `transport.csv`, this will be *less* efficient as I have chosen to go for still a single handle on the file. If I knew that that would be a problem, then I would rework it to use the `DictReader` instead of pulling it all into a tuple immediately (including changing the way of treating `len(items)`, and <s>reinitialise the `DictReader` afterwards</s> `f.seek(0)` (good suggestion, Evpok!) and `f.readline()` to get rid of the header line.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

with open('transport.csv', 'rb') as f:
    items = tuple(csv.DictReader(f))

charges_per_inv = defaultdict(float)
for row in items:
    charges_per_inv[row['Batch#']] += float(row['Amount'])

total = sum(charges_per_inv.values())
print 'The total charges is, ', total
print 'The average charge is, ', total / len(items)

a = raw_input('Enter Invoice#: ')

invoice_amount = 0.0
invoice_items = 0
for row in items:
    invoice_num = row['Invoice#']
    if invoice_num == a:
        invoice_amount += float(row['Amount'])
        invoice_items += 1

print 'The total charges is, ', invoice_amount
print 'The average charge is, ', invoice_amount / invoice_items
```

The efficiency problem I mentioned could also be removed by getting the invoice number at the start and so only having one loop which needs to access the CSV file:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

a = raw_input('Enter Invoice#: ')

with open('transport.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)

    num_items = 0
    charges_per_inv = defaultdict(float)
    invoice_amount = 0.0
    invoice_items = 0

    for row in reader:
        charges_per_inv[row['Batch#']] += float(row['Amount'])
        invoice_num = row['Invoice#']
        if invoice_num == a:
            invoice_amount += float(row['Amount'])
            invoice_items += 1
        num_items += 1

    total = sum(charges_per_inv.values())
    print 'The total charges is, ', total
    print 'The average charge is, ', total / num_items

    print 'The total invoice item charges is, ', invoice_amount
    print 'The average invoice item charge is, ', invoice_amount / invoice_items
```

If you have any questions to ask about things that I've done, please ask.

Comment: This is really efficient. I'm new to python and programming. This really provided me some answers on how to open and read files efficiently.

Comment: @amp28: I hope it helps you. If you'd like to know why I did anything, please do ask; I'm quite willing to explain.